# Javascript - alert not shown if page is inactive

Tags: javascript, alert

I need an alert which tells the user that the session expired after one hour.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.alert("Session expired");
  location.reload();
}, 3600000);
```

This is working perfectly fine if the tab is active, but if it is inactive the alert is not shown and the page will reload without notifying the user. Is there a way to wait for the user to click the "ok" button of the alert when he switches to the page, or something similar that notifies the user?

Thanks

Comment: not really with the native `.alert()`  method. but you can create your own modal and create a event on the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (document.hidden === false) {
    window.alert("Session expired");
    location.reload();
  }
  else {
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      if (document.hidden === false) {
        window.alert("Session expired");
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
}, 3600000);
```

Solved with document.hidden property and visibilitychange listener

Answer (score -1):

Hi Goalpang just worked for me, just try it might solve your question, you will also see a dot remaining in inactive browser meaning waiting for ok to be pressed

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    if(window.alert("Session expired")){
    }; 
    location.reload();
  },4000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [alert returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert#return_value), so the if block never executes